# how to get value time from import excell laravel maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel, excellentexport

hello am usin laravel excell maatwebsite how to get value time from excell? i always got error __construct(): Failed to parse time string (@0.45833333333333) at position 16 (3): Unexpected character how to solve this? is any function can i use in phpoffice like get date ?

note:
jam_masuk & jam_keluar is time data type

code

```
 public function collection(Collection $collection)
    {
        foreach($collection as $key => $row){
            if ($key >= 4){
               $tanggal = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[2]);
               $jam_masuk = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::PHPToExcel($row[3]);
                DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('pga_master_absen')->insert([
                    'noreg' => $row[0],
                    'nama' => $row[1],
                    'tanggal' => $tanggal,
                    'jam_masuk' => $row[3],
                    'jam_pulang' => $row[4],
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your database column of `jam_masuk` and `jam_pulang` is a datetime colum, you can parse your date with using `Carbon` facade using `Carbon::parse($row[3]);` [Official Carbon Docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) . This formats the date time in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVE I CHANGE FORMAT CELL IN EXCELL TO TYPE TEXT